# Disable some responsive levels in bootstrap 3?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

What's the cleanest way to disable certain responsive levels in Bootstrap 3? I'm trying to disable the tablet level (col-sm) and the wide screen mode (col-lg).

Wondering what the simplest way to do that is.

Answer (score 1):

There are three ways that I can think off of the top of my head.

The first I do not like as much but I will say it anyway.

Crack open the grid.less or grid.scss (depending on which you are using) and comment out the portions for the col-sm and col-lg.  This will effectively give you what you want.

The second solution allows you to update your version of bootstap without having to worry about your changes being overridden. However it also requires less or scss.

Make your own grid.less / grid.scss file and only include the media's that you want, I'm guessing medium is what you are targeting. Then use your own file to do all the includes and swap where the original grid file was included with your own grid file.  That way you can always pull down a clean copy of bootstrap and as long as their files are in the same location you should get a clean compile.

Dirtiest way I thought of as I was typing would be to change the variable for the widths of the other two sizes to make them match the size you are targeting, md, that might make for some horrible side-effects, but it might just work.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `col-xs-X` classes since they are constant percentage widths.

```
<!-- Don't use .container at all or you will have to
     override a lot of responsive styles. -->
<div class="non-responsive">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <h1>Welcome to Non-responsive Land</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-8">
      <!-- More content, more content -->
    </div>
  </div>
```

user this type of code

```
.non-responsive {
  /* Margin/padding copied from Bootstrap */
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;

  /* Set width to your desired site width */
  width: 1170px;
}
```

For more info visit [LINK](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#disable-responsive)